# New column based on a row with conditions in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do an operation with Dataframes but i'm not sure how I can solve the problem using the built-in Pandas Operations (Actualy my code is based on a for so I'm trying to build a more elegant solution). 
Given the following Dataframes, defined with the columns described below

```
original_df = [o1, o2, o3, o4]
weights_df = [w1, w2, w3, w4]
conditions_df = [c1, c2, c3, c4]
```

I need to built a new column on *original_df* based on the division of *o1/w1* but depending on the value of *c1*, with takes the values ["+" or "-" I need to do the *-o1/w1* operation.

As long as I did was:

```
orignal_df['newcolumn'] = original_df / weights_df
```

Where of course I divided the two terms but without applying the condition, I'm trying to do with map and apply functions but I'm not sure how I can add the third column into the function.

Comment: `original_df = [o1, o2, o3, o4]` is list of DataFrames? Or columns names of one dataframe?

Comment: Are column names of one Dataframe

Comment: OK, what is size of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for mask by condition:

```
#data from lisa answer
#df = pd.DataFrame({'x':original_df, 'y':weights_df, 'z':conditions_df})

df['new_feature'] = df['x'] / df['y'] *  np.where(df['z'] > 2, 1, -1)
print (df)
     x   y  z  new_feature
0  100  10  1        -10.0
1  200  20  2        -10.0
2  300  30  3         10.0
3  400  40  4         10.0
```

**Timings**:

```
#4k rows
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

#lisa answer
In [95]: %timeit df['new_feature1'] = df.apply(lambda p: div(p['x'], p['y'], p['z']), axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 123 ms per loop

In [96]: %timeit df['new_feature2'] = df['x'] / df['y'] *  np.where(df['z'] > 2, 1, -1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 595 µs per loop
```

Comment: About the size of the data it's variable, I'm writing an algorithm for Clustering Profiling, so the size depends in the number of observations of the dataset. I'll try to apply the numpy.where also, Thanks!

Comment: OK, so need `apply solution`? If yes, then it is no problem. Is possible upvote my solution too? Or is necessary modify my solution because `apply` is slow? Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

```
original_df = [100, 200, 300, 400]
weights_df = [10, 20, 30, 40]
conditions_df = [1, 2, 3, 4]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':original_df, 'y':weights_df, 'z':conditions_df})
def div(x, y, z):
    if z > 2:
        return float(x/y)
    else:
        return float(-1*x/y)

df['new_feature'] = df.apply(lambda p: div(p['x'], p['y'], p['z']), axis=1)
```

This is one way of solving. If your conditions_df contains '+'/'-' then you can change the condition in `def div(x, y, z)` accordingly.

Comment: Merging the 3 Dataframes into one  works for me. Thanks :)

Comment: I think `apply` here is not necessary, because it is slow. Check timings in my answer.